# requestFocus() also triggers onClick()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `TextField` and a `Button`. First on screen load TextField is focused. When I press `ENTER` while I am on the TextField, the button gets focused. The problem is that when the button gets focused, it also triggers its onClick() method, thus `"Clicked on Button"` is printed.

How to prevent when calling `focusRequester[1].requestFocus()` to trigger Button's onClick() method? I only need to focus that button.

```kotlin
val focusRequester = remember { listOf(FocusRequester(), FocusRequester()) }
val focusedState = remember { mutableStateListOf(true, false) }

Column {
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = TextFieldValue("test"),
        onValueChange = { },
        modifier = Modifier
            .onKeyEvent {
                if (it.type == KeyEventType.KeyDown) {
                    if (it.key.keyCode == Key.Enter.keyCode) {
                        focusRequester[1].requestFocus()

                        return@onKeyEvent true
                    }
                }
                false
            }
            .focusRequester(focusRequester[0])
            .onFocusChanged {
                focusedState[0] = it.isFocused
            }
            .focusable(),
        colors = textFieldColors(focusedState[0]))

    OutlinedButton(modifier = Modifier
        .focusRequester(focusRequester[1])
        .onFocusChanged {
            focusedState[1] = it.isFocused
        }
        .focusable(),
        colors = getColorByFocusedState(focusedState[1]),
        onClick = { println("Clicked on Button.") }) {
        Text(text = "Button")
    }
}

LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    focusRequester[0].requestFocus()
}
```

Comment: I think this article can help you https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/touch-input/handling-interactions